# Binding Control when inside DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to bind a combo box's font family to another combo box's font family. It works fine, until I put a data template inside the combo box I'm trying to pull from. See the code below:

```
<Window Height="350" x:Class="MainWindow" Width="525" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Name="ComboBoxStackPanel" Margin="6" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ComboBox FontFamily="Wingdings" Name="SS0">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="SSD">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Row" Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Name="SS1" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="Wingdings"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox FontFamily="{Binding FontFamily, ElementName=SS1}" SelectedIndex="1">
            Test
            <ComboBoxItem FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Normal">Regular</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Normal">Italic</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Bold">Bold</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold">Bold Italic</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I can access SS0 just fine, but when I try to access SS1, it fails. I've tried using RelativeSource, but I'm confused how to use it in this context.

Comment: You seem to be missing an `ItemsSource` on your SS0 combo box.

Comment: You can't access SS1, bind to SS0 combobox.

Answer (score 0):

the `DataTemplate` has a `VisualTree` property and you can use this to interrogate its contents, however the contents dont exist until the template is applied.